# Swift project Linker Error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm getting "Undefined symbols for architecture armv7" error from my Swift 2.3 project. This happens after I tried to add csv parser library to my project and I agreed to convert the library to swift 2.3 when XCode showed the prompt.

Since I'm getting 500~ errors coming from the library and the deadline is approaching, I decided to uninstall it. But I'm stuck with 7 errors. I remember seeing this error when I first add AWS library to my project. I think I resolve this by removing -obj parameter somewhere. I'm not entirely sure.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anybody who is having similar issue - open pods debug file under Pods folder. Remove "-Objc" from "OTHER_LDFLAGS = ..." line. Voila, it solves my problem.